# Show that in any triangle with sides $a,b,c$ we have $(a+b+c)^2<4(ab+bc+ca)$

Tags: inequality, triangles

Just expanded the bracket and needed to prove $a^2+b^2+c^2<2(ab+bc+ca)$.
We know that $a^2+b^2+c^2>ab+bc+ca$ but what next?

Comment: **Hints**: $c<a+b \wedge a <b+c \wedge b< a+c$.

Comment: There was some sort of name for this substitution:  there are $x,y,z > 0$ such that $a = x+y, \; \; b = y+z, \; \; c = z + x .$  See how quickly this shows $a+b > c$  for example. In reverse, define by $ y=\frac{a+b-c}{2}  $